# Как отсортировать список, состоящий из классов?

Tags: python, классы, сортировка

Есть список:

```
a = [W('A', 101, 1), W('B', -1, 0), W('A', 11, 0), W('A', 111, -11)]
```

`W` - это класс. Для сортировки используется `W.sort()`, который сортирует список по трём элементам:

```
W('A', 11, 0), W('A',101, 1), W('A', 111, -11), W('B', -1, 0)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача не совсем понятна, но вот вам такой вариант. Для того, чтобы можно было использовать любую стандартную сортировку с вашим классом, в нём достаточно описать функцию сравнения экземпляров класса `__lt__`:

```
class W:
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.data = args

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.data < other.data

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'W{str(self.data)}'

a = [W('A', 101, 1), W('B', -1, 0), W('A', 11, 0), W('A', 111, -11)]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Вывод:

```
[W('A', 11, 0), W('A', 101, 1), W('A', 111, -11), W('B', -1, 0)]
```

Совет про сортировку экземпляров класса подсмотрен на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010558/8324991).

Answer (score 1):

Для нормального ответа, конечно, нужно привести код самого класса, но предположим, что вы передаете в конструктор три параметра класса - `a`, `b`, `c`. Тогда для сортировки сразу по 3м полям нужно передать в метод `sort` функцию сортировки, которая будет возвращать кортеж из трех значений в порядке приоритетности сортировки по ним. Удобнее всего это сделать через lambda-функцию.

```py
a = [W('A', 101, 1), W('B', -1, 0), W('A', 11, 0), W('A', 111, -11)]

a.sort(key=lambda obj: (obj.a, obj.b, obj.c))
```